# Number of real roots of $2 \cos\left(\frac{x^2+x}{6}\right)=2^x+2^{-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

Find the number of real roots of

$ \cos \,\left(\dfrac{x^2+x}{6}\right)= \dfrac{2^x+2^{-x}}{2}$

1) 0

2) 1

3) 2

4)  None of these

My guess is to approach it in graphical way. But equation seems little difficult.

Comment: Since it is multiple choice, can't you just plug in the options and see if any of them hold true?

Comment: The equation of the title is different from the one at the start of the posted question.

Comment: @mathamphetamines: The question is asking for the number of real roots. What prevents it from being 42 or infinity or etc?

Comment: This is why reading is an important skill to have! :(

Comment: IMO, both $1$ and $2$ (double root) are acceptable as answers.

Comment: x = 0 is a root *and* a minimum point.

Answer (score 10):

HINT:

For real $x,\dfrac{2^x+2^{-x}}2\ge\sqrt{2^x\cdot 2^{-x}}=1$

and for real $y,\cos y\le1$

Comment: Ok so answer is 0. But I dont know this inequality u used. Can u explain it plz?

Comment: Is it AM, GM inequality?

Comment: @User786, The 1st one is AM-GM. We have $2\cos\dfrac{x^2+x}6\le2$ and $2^x+2^{-x}\ge2$. For the existence of the solution, what do we need?

Comment: @Foggy answer is not zero,when does $\dfrac{2^x+2^{-x}}{2}$ becomes $1$?

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal $x=0$ is a solution

Answer (score 1):

Rearranging we get $$(2^x)^2-2\cos\dfrac{x^2+x}6(2^x)+1=0\  \ \ \ (0)$$ which is a Quadratic equation in $2^x$

For real $2^x,$ the discriminant must be $\ge0$

i.e., $$\left(2\cos\dfrac{x^2+x}6\right)^2-4=-4\sin^2\dfrac{x^2+x}6\ge0\  \ \ \ (1)$$

As $\sin\dfrac{x^2+x}6$ is real, $$\sin^2\dfrac{x^2+x}6\ge0\iff-4\sin^2\dfrac{x^2+x}6\le0\ \ \ \ (2)$$

By $(1),(2);$  $$\sin^2\dfrac{x^2+x}6=0\implies\cos\dfrac{x^2+x}6=\pm1$$

What happens to $(0)$ if $(i):\cos\dfrac{x^2+x}6=1$

Or if $(ii):\cos\dfrac{x^2+x}6=-1$

Remember for real $x, 2^x>0$

Comment: :for $(1) x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+48n}}{2}$ for $(2)  x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+24(2n\pm 1)\pi}}{2}$.If we take $n\mathbb N$, then there are infinite number of real roots?Please check my argument