# The equation $2\cos^2(\frac x2)\sin^2x=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$ where $0\le x \le \pi/2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

LHS becomes 
$$(\cos x+1)(\sin^2x)$$

I checked the range using a graph [image]

For RHS, the max and min values are $(2,\infty)$ hence no solution is possible. But how can I find the range for LHS numerically?

Comment: Let $\cos x =t$, LHS is then $(t+1)(1-t^2)$

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121453/number-of-real-roots-of-2-cos-left-fracx2x6-right-2x2-x

Answer (score 3):

Note that the exact range is not terrybly important if our end goal is to show that there can be no solutions to the equation.

We know that $-1\leq \sin x, \cos x\leq 1$, which means that $0\leq \cos x + 1\leq 2$.

If it were possible for the LHS to become $2$, then we must have $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ hit their maximum exactly simultaneously. This cannot happen. So the maximal value of the left-hand side is strictly less than $2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$2\cos^2\Big(\frac{x}{2}\Big)\sin^2x\leq 2\forall x\in\mathbb R$$
(because each of the terms multiplied by $2$ are $\leq 1$.)
$$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\geq 2\forall x\in\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$$
Equality holds on $RHS$ iff $x=\pm 1$, but equality doesn't hold in bound for $LHS$ for that. Hence, no solution.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by ‘hold in bound for LHS’

Comment: @Aditya These are bounds on the LHS and the RHS. For the RHS bound you can attain equality for the right choice of $x$, but for the bound on the LHS, you can't get equality. That's what that sentence is trying to say.

Comment: Bound for LHS is 2, I am saying that $x$ for which RHS =2 , doesn't satisfy LHS=2

Comment: But the graph says that LHS cannot be more than some 1.2, so how did you get two?

Comment: I am claiming that it is bounded above by $2$ trivially. It may not be sharp.

Comment: @Aditya Because $\sin x\leq 1$ and $0\leq(1+\cos x)\leq 2$, so $\sin x\cdot (1+\cos x)\leq 2$. It's not the _best_ possible bound we can find, but it's very easy to find and prove, and it's good enough. We don't really care that the _true_ maximum is closer to $1.2$. We know it's less than $2$ and that's all we need.

Answer (score 0):

$$2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}\cdot \sin^2 x=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\;\;\forall\; x\in \bigg[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg]$$

$$2(1+\cos x)^2\cdot (1-\cos x)=2\bigg(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\bigg)$$

Arithmetic Geometric Inequality for $$\frac{(1+\cos x)+(1+\cos x)+(2-2\cos x)}{3}\geq \bigg[(1+\cos x)^2(2-2\cos x)\bigg]^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

$$(1+\cos x)^2(2-2\cos x)\leq \bigg(\frac{4}{3}\bigg)^{3}$$

Equality hold when $\displaystyle 1+\cos x=2-2\cos x\Rightarrow \cos x=\frac{1}{3}$

and $$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\geq 2\Rightarrow 2\bigg(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\bigg)\geq 4$$

Equality hold when $x=1$

Left side $\neq $ Right side

No real solution exists.